# Find window by class name in outlook

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, outlook, office-interop

I am trying to get window detail from windowlcassname. It is not returning window detail from by class name. I have attached Class name screenshot here.
[image]

My code is following

```
 public static int SearchForWindow(string wndclass, string title)
    {
        int nWinHandle = FindWindow("NetUIHWND", null);

        if (nWinHandle == 0)
        {
            // handle the error message
        }
       
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);
```

but above code nWinHandle  is retuning always o. I am not sure about mistaken.
Thanks

Comment: What's the overall goal here? Working directly with window classes is rarely the right way to approach interacting with other programs these days. You might be better server by looking at e.g. [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview)

Comment: I am trying to check it is available or not . If it is available we need to set magine on my outlook top custom panel in VSTO

Answer (score 0):

[FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) only finds the **top** level windows, which means you can only find the `Explorer` or `Inspector` windows in Outlook. But you don't need `FindWindow` for that - you can grab the HWND of an `Explorer` or `Inspector` object by casting it to [IOleWindow](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IOleWindow.html?diff=y) and calling `IOleWindows.GetWindow()`. Once you have the top level handle, you can enumerate its children using the [EnumChildWindows](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows) Win API function.

Note that `"NetUIHWND"` is used in more than one place in Outlook, so you will most likely find multiple matches. You can use a unique combination of the window/parent/sibling class names to figure out if you have the right window. All of that can (and will) change without a notice - Outlook UI layout gets changed fairly frequently.